# A characterization of convexity

Tags: geometry, convexity, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, gt.geometric-topology

While doing some research on polytopes I came to the following question. Maybe it's already somewhere but anyway I'll post it here.

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be such that, for every plane $P$, $P\cap X$ is simply connected. Is $X$ convex?

I'm not sure, but I think maybe it's necesary to assume some well behaving like local simple connectedness. Anyway I think this is true with the apropiate asumptions. I would not be surprised if it was true just as stated.

Probably this is true even in greater dimensions.

Comment: By simply connected, you implicitely mean connected and simply connected, right?

Comment: For dimensions $n$ greater than 3, are you assuming that you intersect planes with $X$ or that you intersect $n-1$-planes with $X$?

Comment: n-1 planes and yes, connected and simply connected

Comment: @CristosA.Ruiz, actually it should be $2$-planes (together with $0$- and $1$-connectedness). More generally, one could consider $k$-planes and $j$-connectedness for every $j=0\ 1\ \ldots\ k-1$.

Comment: @CristosA.Ruiz, I feel that it would be cleaner to state in your question: "connected and simply connected". (In topology we say "connected up to dimension $n-1$, and similar; we don't say connected in dimension $n-1$--ok, not often :-).

Comment: The article https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02045 answers your question, see Prop. 2.5, and explains the extent of generalisation you can expect. Cheers!
\

Comment: @Farhad: That proposition seems to deal only with $k$-convexity, without relating it to convexity, right? How, then, does it address the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about some tomography? This should work if $X$ is open. Assume $X\subset \mathbb R^3$ is nonempty and for every plane $H$ the intersection $H\cap X$ is either contractible or empty. (Note that an open subset of the plane is contractible if it is ((nonempty,) connected, and) simply connected.)

Claim 1: $X$ is contractible.

Proof: Consider the space of all pairs $(x,H)$, $x\in X$ and $H$ a plane containing $x$.

Fiber this by $(x,H)\mapsto x$. It's a trivial bundle over $X$ with fiber $P^2$.

Fiber the same thing by $(x,H)\mapsto H$. The nonempty fibers are contractible, so the domain is homotopy equivalent to the image, which in turn fibers over $P^2$ with contractible fibers.

So $X\times P^2$ has the same homotopy type as $P^2$, and upon further inspection $X$ is contractible.

Claim 2: $X$ is convex.

Proof: Let $L$ be any line whose intersection with $X$ is nonempty, and play the same game again with pairs $(x,H)$, but now the plane $H$ is constrained to contain $L$. Call the space of all such pairs $Y$. On the one hand, $Y$ is equivalent to the circle $P^1$ by the same kind of argument as before. On the other hand, $Y$ is the blowup of the $3$-manifold $X$ along the $1$-manifold $X\cap L$. The complement $Y'$ of $(X\cap L)\times P^1$ in $Y$ is the same as the complement of $X\cap L$ in $X$, so it is connected. Therefore all of the group $H_1(Y,Y')$ comes from $H_1(Y)$. But the latter group is of rank $1$ while the former is isomorphic to $H_0( (X\cap L)\times P^1)$. (I am using mod $2$ coefficients.) It follows that $X\cap L$ is connected.

Maybe this generalizes to $\mathbb R^n$. The hypothesis I am thinking of is that every nonempty hyperplane section is contractible, or equivalently $(n-2)$-connected. I don't believe that every hyperplane section simply connected is enough if $n>3$

Comment: I don't think that Claim 2 is true if $X$ is the interior of my modification of Diego Matessi's example: $X=\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}_+: x<0 \text{ or } x^2<y^2+z^2\}.$ 

Comment: Your $X$ intersects the plane $x=z+1$ in a disconnected set.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! The vertex of the parabola is below the $xy$-plane, so there are two pieces. Once I drew it, it became obvious.

Comment: I'm chosing this one as the correct answer. There was also Matessi's correct counterexample and Pak's reference (by the way, that book looks really good). But I think there's more merit in this one, and it looks correct to me, also I don't know if the case of $X$ open was known, and the method used to solve it is very appealing to me.
Thanks very much for your responses!

Comment: Thanks. I don't swear that it's correct, though.

Comment: I didn't know for a fact that this key step was legitimate: weak contractibility of the fibers of $p:Y\to X$ implies that $p$ is a weak homotopy equivalence if $Y\subset X\mathbb R^n$ is open and $p$ is the projection. But it's OK, even if $\mathbb R^n$ is replaced by any space. A student of mine rn across this lemma in another context. The reference is the appendix of Graeme Segal, Classifying Spaces Related to Foliations, Topology vol. 17 pp. 367-382.

Answer (score 17):

A version of this is well known:

> Let $X\subset \Bbb R^3$ be a compact
> set and suppose every intersection of
> $X$ by a plane is contractible. Then
> $X$ is convex.

This is due to Schreier (1933) in $\Bbb R^3$, and Aumann (1936) generalized this to higher dimensions.  See this and other related results in Ju.D. Burago and V.A. Zalgaller, [Sufficient criteria of convexity](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01476847), *J. Math. Sci.* **10** (1978), 395–435.  Incidentally, this a (hard) exercise in my book [Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/geompol8.pdf) (Exc. 1.25).

Answer (score 10):

In coordinates $(x,y,z)$, consider { $z \geq 0$} and remove from it the half line { $(t,0,0)  | t > 0 $}. You get something non convex, but it seems to me that it also satisfies your property. Maybe you need some boundedness?

Comment: Nice example, that can be made closed by removing a semi-infinite open cylinder instead of a half-line.

Comment: @Benoit: Would it not then be possible to choose $P$ slanting so that it clips a bit of the base of the cylinder near the origin, and so creating a hole in $P \cap X$?  Maybe I misunderstand what you intend.

Comment: Joseph: That's right! It can be fixed by removing a half-cone $\{ (x,y,z): x>0, x^2>y^2+z^2\}$ instead. Then $P\cap X$ is  $P_+\setminus Q$, where $P_+$ is a half-plane and $Q$ is empty, a point, a wedge, a region above a parabola or hyperbola, or a an elliptical segment with the chord along the boundary line of $P_+.$ 

Comment: As Tom Goodwillie pointed out, the intersection with $x=z+1$ is disconnected (it is the region above a parabola whose vertex is below the boundary of the half-plane), so this doesn't work, either.

Comment: Unboundedness is not the issue. Diego Matessi's example can be modified by intersecting with max(|x|,|y|,z)<1.

Comment: @Joseph: yes,I guess you're right.
@Victor: you mean the region on the sides of the parabola, right?

Comment: Benoît: Yes, the removed region is above the parabola, so the remaining set is on the sides.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Corrected.

Here is an elementary statement with a similar flavor (this does not answer the question).

> Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $\mathcal{F}$ a family of functions $f: M\to \mathbb{R}^{n_f}$ with the following properties:
>
> a. $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under linear projections
>
> b. The pre-image $f^{-1}(c)\subset M$ under $f\in\mathcal{F}$ of any point $c\in \mathbb{R}^{n_f}$ is either empty or connected.
>
> Then the image $f(M)$ of $M$ under any  $f\in\mathcal{F}$ is convex.

Using Morse theory, Atiyah proved that these hypotheses hold for the moment maps of Hamiltonian torus actions on a compact symplectic manifold $M$<sup>**1**</sup> and concluded that the image $\mu(M)$ is a convex polytope whose vertices are the images of the fixed points.

Atiyah, *Convexity and commuting Hamiltonians*,
Bull. London Math. Soc. 14 (1982), no. 1, 1–15

---

**Footnote**

<sup>**1**</sup> More precisely, families of commuting Hamiltonians which generate a compact subgroup in $Diff(M).$

Comment: There is something wrong: the continuous image of a connected set is connected, so that the right-hand side is satisfied for all connected $K$.


Comment: Hmm... you are right, I need to check the paper. It's possible that the condition is really in terms of intersections with hyperplanes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true for non locally-connected sets. Take a path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one end that accumulates to a subsegment of $\gamma$ (in a $\sin(1/x)$ way). Take the product of $\gamma$ with $\mathbb{R}$, and add the interior of $\gamma$ times $\{0\}$.

If you want it to be compact, take $\gamma\times\{0\}$ union with a cone based on $\gamma$.

Note that $\gamma$ is also a weird example of a compact set of the plane that is pathwise connected, simply connected, and whose complement has two connected components.

Comment: Re "weird example of a compact set": what you mean is probably a "quasicircle" (Hatcher, Alg Top, Sec 1.3, Ex 7), because the complement of the closure of the graph of $\sin(1/x), x>0$ is clearly contractible.  

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried to describe.